# Is there a way to trace registers across all processes?

Tags: cpu, trace, cpu-registers

I've been playing around with processor-trace for a while and it seems to essentially be a very close to the metal debugger, but I'm wondering if there is some way that you can record a very short rolling history of the contents of all registers across all execution environments? Something like a system-wide processor-trace.

As I'm saying this, the answer seems a bit self-evident: that this could be a huge security issue, but the motivation for the project is rather security angled.

I'd essentially be looking to log all values and addresses matching a very specific format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying the scheduler of your OS. Attach to the scheduler and log all task-switches. Multitasking will take care of that you will get a time-sliced sample of all registers of all tasks of all logical processors...

It's not easy, but doable.